# Getting KeyError: 3, while trying to run this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-loops

I am trying to create a master dataframe using the features. Trying to do a `for` loop , but I am getting `KeyError 3`, whereas, the Youtube video I am learning it from does not get this error and able to run the code smoothly. This code is the last leg of a long code. but everything else, except this part has been successfully executed. Please guide me through

```
for i in range(0,len(dictlist)):
    if colFeat[i] == 'macd':     
        coldID = colFeat[i] + str(keylist[6][0] + str(keylist[6][1]))     
        masterFrame[colID] = dictlest[i]

    else:    
        for j in keylist[i]: 
            for k in list(dictlist[i][j]):             
                colID = colFeat[i] + str(j) + k            
                masterFrame[colID] = dictlist[i][j][k]

masterFrame
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-3bb03ae5562c> in <module>
     11         for j in keylist[i]:
     12 
---> 13             for k in list(dictlist[i][j]):
     14 
     15                 colID = colFeat[i] + str(j) + k

KeyError: 3
```

Comment: Can you add the dictlist dict?

Comment: It is hard helping you without knowing what are `dictlist` or `keylist`

Comment: Thank you @ Leo Arad @ Tomerikoo,  the issue has been resolved for now. Appreciate your response.